# Why is a lower quantile greater than a higher quantile?

Tags: google-bigquery

Here's my [query](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/savedquery/226352634162:654c3b0d1cff41efb14005bf935911f8)

```
SELECT
  APPROX_QUANTILES(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(lighthouse,
      '$.audits.first-meaningful-paint.rawValue'),1000)[OFFSET(100)] AS p10,
  APPROX_QUANTILES(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(lighthouse,
      '$.audits.first-meaningful-paint.rawValue'),1000)[OFFSET(250)] AS p25,
  APPROX_QUANTILES(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(lighthouse,
      '$.audits.first-meaningful-paint.rawValue'),1000)[OFFSET(500)] AS p50,
  APPROX_QUANTILES(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(lighthouse,
      '$.audits.first-meaningful-paint.rawValue'),1000)[OFFSET(750)] AS p75,
  APPROX_QUANTILES(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(lighthouse,
      '$.audits.first-meaningful-paint.rawValue'),1000)[OFFSET(900)] AS p90
FROM
  `httparchive.har.2017_06_01_android_pages`
WHERE
  lighthouse != 'null'
```

And the results:

```
Row p10     p25     p50     p75     p90  
1   13223.9 2904.2  4851.2  6817    8352.1
```

Why is p10 (13223.9) greater than p90 (8352.1)?

Edit: This seems to be a transient issue with BigQuery. I'm getting expected results now. Filed a bug.

Comment: I get 1328.8 for p10

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Just so you don't think I'm crazy: http://imgur.com/a/q6oGW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inputs are string, not floating point numbers :) If you want floating point ordering, you need to cast:

```
SELECT
  quantiles[OFFSET(100)] AS p10,
  quantiles[OFFSET(250)] AS p25,
  quantiles[OFFSET(500)] AS p50,
  quantiles[OFFSET(750)] AS p75,
  quantiles[OFFSET(900)] AS p90
FROM (
  SELECT
    APPROX_QUANTILES(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(lighthouse,
        '$.audits.first-meaningful-paint.rawValue') AS FLOAT64),1000) AS quantiles
  FROM
    `httparchive.har.2017_06_01_android_pages`
  WHERE
    lighthouse != 'null'
);
+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
|  p10   |  p25   |  p50   |  p75   |   p90   |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
| 2578.7 | 3944.1 | 5781.3 | 8092.4 | 10785.5 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
```